# How can I use gsub to remove single quot and comma from a column

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have an `awk 'print{$15,$25,$29}'` output in below format which I need to remove the special character symbol(',) using `gsub`. Can anyone help me with a format to use to get the desire output.

current output

```
'abc' 'def', 'ghi'
```

expected output

```
abc def ghi
```

Comment: Have it something like: `awk '{gsub(/\047/,"");print $15,$25,$29}' Input_file` to remove `'` in output.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include a text sample of the input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these work:

```
awk '{gsub(/['\'',]/, ""); print $15,$25,$29}' Input_file
awk '{gsub(/[\047,]/, ""); print $15,$25,$29}' Input_file
```

The first uses `'\''` to escape a single quote. The second uses octal notations for the single quote.

The `[]` creates a class including the single quote and commas, which are both replaced with "".